# Create table syntax in Android SQLite corrections

Tags: android, sqlite

Sorry I had to remove my earlier post because of work . . here is a more generic fix to the problem I was having that does not reference anything in particular but works more like a skeleton of how it should be done using a solution i was given.

///--------------------Most Recent Edits to this Post----------------------------------

Okay guys and gals, turns out there is no error in my syntax here however my methodology  was not the smartest. I was filled in on how to do this correctly for those of you on here who need a solution here it is for creating multiple tables in a single database with android (at least the way I did it.) .......

Okay so clear all the dbHelper classes imbedded in your dbAdapters and create a stand alone dbhelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. By doing this you can use your classes to access the information while referencing the SliteOpenHelper stand alone dbAdapter. Here is an example of the Stand alone helper class and one of my adapters i used to access it.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
//-----------------------------------Member Variables---------------------------
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // nothing here cause not upgrading version right now
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME  + Table1DbAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME  + Table2DbAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE);

        onCreate(db);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        db.execSQL(Table1DbAdapter.CREATE_TABLE_ONE);
        db.execSQL(Table2DbAdapter.CREATE_TABLE_TWO);

    }

}
```

// and one example of how to use this helper from a class that accesses table1 (done the same way for all other tables)

```
public class Table1DbAdapter {


static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table1";


public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


 static final String CREATE_TABLE_ONE =
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
            + KEY_BODY + " text not null )";


private final Context mCtx;

public Table1DbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

// create the database
public Table1DbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException{
    this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    this.mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// create an entry
public long createEntry(String title, String body){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return 
        this.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
// delete an Entry
public boolean deleteEntry(long rowId){
    return 
        this.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" +rowId, null) > 0;
}
// fetch all Entries
public Cursor fetchAllEntries(){
    return this.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, 
                    KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
// fetch an Entry
public Cursor fetchEntry(long rowId) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor = 
    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, 
                    KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID +"="+ 
                        rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
// update an Entry
public boolean updateEntry(long rowId, String title, String body){
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return
    this.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "="+ rowId, null)> 0;

}
// close the database
public void close(){
    mDbHelper.close();
}

}
```

// I hope this helps.... sorry again for the deletion earlier but this is how it should be done. . . at least until I find something more efficient

Comment: i keep getting a no such table error when I run this

Comment: Post the `Logcat` with the exception and the part of the code where you get that `Exception`.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ATG.C3FactSystemTabbed/com.ATG.C3FactSystemTabbed.C3FactSystemTabbedActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ATG.C3FactSystemTabbed/com.ATG.C3FactSystemTabbed.AmenitiesActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: amenities: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body FROM amenities

Comment: since you're using SQLiteOpenHelper class you should uninstall app from device/emulator ... to avoid this you should delete all tables in onUpgrade implementation and recreate them with  increasing database_version ... why all this stuff is needed ... well , it's prolly you've already created database and then you add some table and onCreate is not called again ...

Comment: sounds like you're selecting already from table that doesn't exist...

Comment: Are you sure that the word 'amenities' is spelled correctly when you defined this string `AmenitiesDbAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE`?

Comment: yes, but this would have no effect because of how i define the table name in my sql syntax, I call it directly from the AmenitiesDbAdapter class.

Comment: Does the database already exist from a previous version of your app? In other words are you trying to 'add' a table using that code in your question or is this a 'first run' scenario?

Comment: yes, it is a new version. If i uninstall the app it does not delete the db. How do i use the adb tools to delete the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, no offence but your methodology really needs some work. That code is a complete tangle.

As to explaining the reason for the exception...

At no point in that code does an instance of `MainDbAdapter` ever get created. The result is, its `onCreate(...)` method is never called so basically you don't have any tables (all of them, I mean, not just the amenities table will be missing).

To be honest I wouldn't nest a derived `SQLiteOpenHelper` into an 'adapter' of any sort.

Create a stand-alone class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and just create an instance of it whenever you need it.

Get rid of the nested `DatabaseHelper` classes in your 'adapter' classes, re-build, look at what eclipse complains about (assuming you're using eclipse) and then patch it up by pointing everything at your stand-alone `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: If i wanted to reference the main db class from the other two, how would i do that? Even if it is a bad practice....

Comment: Nevermind the tables still wont get created. I dont understand. I use the databaseHelper stand alone class and create references to is with my dbadapters but the onCreate() still doesn't run

Answer (score 1):

The best source to get to know SQLite syntax is [SQLite Homepage](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html)

And your syntax looks correct.

**EDIT**: Yep, you'll need to delete database from app folder and let application create a new database for you like someone in the comment suggested you to do. Because `onCreate()` method checks if database exists or not and if not then creates a new one.

You can delete database by going fo DDMS in Eclipse. The databases are usually stored in

```
/data/data/your.applications.package/databases
```

Comment: can you post code how you create and connect to your database?

Comment: it is under my posted question with the title Unable to start activity: no such table.  Do you mind jumping there so i dont have to repost it? thanks

Comment: actually this is a logcat...what i asked is to post your whole class so that we can see what's going on there...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *your database exists*, but your table (amenities) does not.

Therefore onCreate() is never called because the DB exists already.

When the SELECT query is subsequently run, it throws the exception.

I'm pretty sure that if you use a debugger and step through your code, you'll see this happening.

**Solution**:

- Delete the DB from your device OR
- Execute your CREATE TABLE statement directly from sqlite3

Comment: how do i delete the db from my device?

Comment: From the command line run `adb shell` [see manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) and then `rm` the .db file.